# Shortcuts for removing and editing in a listview in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview that is a list of events. For each event, I want to have shortcut icons right next to its title for editing and removing. If I tab one of those, it should bring me to another Intent for editing/removing events. How do I achieve this?

My xml has a listview like this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```

and for each text view:

```
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
 android:id="@+id/rowTextView"   
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:padding="10dp"  
 android:textSize="16sp" >  
</TextView>
```

Thank you!

Comment: so you want to implement buttons in each list row?? or something else?

Comment: Yes. Basically I want something like this http://imgur.com/hSrVXqP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to create a custom `Adapter` and override the `getView` method like so:

```
    private class MySecondAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MiniTask>
{   
    private ArrayList<MiniTask> list;

    public MySecondAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<MiniTask> miniTaskList) 
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, miniTaskList);
         this.list = new ArrayList<MiniTask>();
         this.list.addAll(miniTaskList);
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        miniTask = miniTaskList.get(position);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.check_list_item_new, null);

            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemTitle);
            holder.commentsPicturesButton = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iAddCommetOrPicture);
            holder.commentsPicturesButton.setTag(position);
            holder.commentsPicturesButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PicturesAndCommentsActivity.class);
                     intent.putExtra(TasksListActivity.KEY_ID, task.getId());
                     intent.putExtra("mini_task_text", miniTask.getTitle());
                     startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            holder.selected = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbCheckListItem);
            holder.selected.setTag(position);
            holder.selected.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {    
                    {                               
                        Log.d(TAG, "pressed the checkbox: " + v.getId() + " in position: " + position + " tag: " +v.getTag() +" and item from array: " + miniTaskList.get(position) );
                        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) v;
                        miniTaskList.get(position).setSelected(checkbox.isChecked());   
                        numOfCheckedMiniTasks = 0;
                        for(int i=0;i<miniTaskList.size();i++)
                        {
                             miniTask = miniTaskList.get(i);
                             if(miniTask.isSelected())
                             {
                                numOfCheckedMiniTasks ++;
                             }
                        }
                        int percent = (int)(numOfCheckedMiniTasks * 100.0f) / miniTaskList.size();
                        Log.d(TAG, "the percentage is: " +percent);
                        tasksRepository.get(tasksRepository.indexOf(task)).setMiniTasksPercentageComplete(percent);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        holder.title.setText(miniTask.getTitle());
        holder.selected.setChecked(miniTask.isSelected());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

In this case I have a checkbox for every row as well, you can ignore it, and the holder is:

```
static class ViewHolder 
{
     TextView title;
     CheckBox selected;
     ImageView commentsPicturesButton;
}
```

While the XML layout for every row is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:background="@drawable/try2"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/cbCheckListItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/checkbox_checklist_selector" 
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_checklist_selector" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvItemTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="13dp"
        android:text="@string/checklist_item_string"
        android:textColor="@color/my_darker_gray" />
  </LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:paddingTop="6.5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iAddCommetOrPicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/comment_or_photo_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/comment_or_photo_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
 holder.iParameterWidget.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                currentParameterPosition = position;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I sort of figured out how to use custom adapter, but I have one issue: How do I know which row the user selects if they click on the edit/delete button on that row?
Basically, inside getView I have a button ImageButton btnDelete = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.deletebutton), and I override its onclick to make it start a new intent for editing the event, but I don't know which row the user selects...

Comment: you can declare a global variable of the activity class that will hold the position of the clicked row, so in the onClick method of your edit/delete button set something like this: globalPostition = position; position is passed to you in the getView method.

Comment: So the position passed into getView is supposed to be the position that the user selects? Because for me, it's always my list's size+1. For example, when my list has 3 elements, it's 4. When my list has 4 elements, it's 5. no matter which item I select.

Comment: the position that passed to the getView method is the position of the currently presented row... so while the list is created every onClick method will receive the position that corresponding with the position in the array where you get the data from... try to log the position in the getView method.

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to create your custom row separately. There are plenty of example you can find. You can see following links to start

http://androidzoo.wordpress.com/2011/10/28/working-with-listview-in-android-customize-listview-add-item-via-a-button-click-and-also-clickable-each-button-in-each-row/

http://www.geekmind.net/2009/11/android-custom-list-item-with-nested.html